# Oracle SQL Developer time difference between records, drop any over 60 minutes

Tags: time, oracle-sqldeveloper, unix-timestamp, difference

hi experts looking for some advice on a problem im stuck on.

im running Oracle Database 18c Enterprise Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0

I have a query where i get all the records for the the max "order_number" per line.

I now need to only pull in the data records for each "order_number" if they were saved to the db within 60 minutes of the previous record.

e.g: i had 8 records for my order_number, the first 3 were all within 60 mins of the previous, but then there was a longer time for +60mins for the next 3 records, then the final 2 records were within 60 mins of their previous.
given the above scenario, i would only need to pull in the final 2 records, as there was records longer than 60mins before that.
also to note, i always need to bring in the max record per line, even if that record is +60mins than previous record

my current code:

```
select * from (
select
ID,
Create_Date_Time_Unix_TimeStamp,
Line,
Order_Number,
to_date('1970-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') + numtodsinterval(Create_Date_Time_Unix_TimeStamp,'SECOND')+ 1/24  as " Date_Time",
max(Order_Number) over (partition by Line) max_Order
from...
join.
where..
)
Order_Number = max_Order
```

sample output data of query if i filter to just one Line:

| ID | Create_Date_Time_Unix_TimeStamp | Line | Order_Number | Date_Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1661170026 | Line1 | 5000 | 22-AUG-2022 13:07:06 |
| 100 | 1661170026 | Line1 | 5000 | 22-AUG-2022 13:07:06 |
| 100 | 1661170026 | Line1 | 5000 | 22-AUG-2022 13:07:06 |
| 172 | 1661170872 | Line1 | 5000 | 22-AUG-2022 13:21:12 |
| 172 | 1661170872 | Line1 | 5000 | 22-AUG-2022 13:21:12 |
| 172 | 1661170872 | Line1 | 5000 | 22-AUG-2022 13:21:12 |
| 180 | 1661170872 | Line1 | 5000 | 22-AUG-2022 13:51:12 |
| 185 | 1661170872 | Line1 | 5000 | 22-AUG-2022 15:00:00 |
| 185 | 1661170872 | Line1 | 5000 | 22-AUG-2022 15:00:00 |
| 185 | 1661170872 | Line1 | 5000 | 22-AUG-2022 15:00:00 |
| 186 | 1661170872 | Line1 | 5000 | 22-AUG-2022 15:10:00 |
| 191 | 1661180040 | Line1 | 5000 | 22-AUG-2022 15:18:00 |

so i need to get only the records that are within 60mins of the previous record taking into consideration that i will always need the most recent record on the line, even if it was +60mins

any ideas would be great thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
WITH prod_prev AS (
  SELECT p.*, 
         COALESCE(lag("Date_Time") OVER (PARTITION BY "Order_Number" ORDER BY "Date_Time" DESC), NULL) AS next_date,
         COALESCE(lag("Date_Time") OVER (PARTITION BY "Order_Number" ORDER BY "Date_Time" DESC), "Date_Time") - "Date_Time" AS diff
    FROM products p    
), 
run_sum AS (
  SELECT p.*,
         SUM(COALESCE(CASE WHEN diff > 1/24 THEN 10000 ELSE diff END,0))
             OVER (PARTITION BY "Order_Number" ORDER BY "Date_Time" DESC) AS run_diff 
    FROM prod_prev p    
)
SELECT * FROM run_sum WHERE run_diff < 10000
ORDER By "Order_Number", "Date_Time" DESC
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3e0294/42/0) ist a fiddle.

Comment: thanks Mihe, where would my original query go in your solution? as the "Date_Time" field is a created column, so where would this sub query go in your solution to get it working? thank you

Comment: As I don't know your tables, the query is based on the output you provided. As for column "Date_Time", the Unix Timestamp would work as well (you'd just have to take into consideration that the timestamp is given in seconds). The basic idea is just to calculate a time difference to the previous record (order by time descending). If it exceeds 60 minutes use a really large number so that the running total can't be the result of normal time intervals. Finally, only the records whose running total is below the large number are considered.

Comment: As for your original query: it's incomplete, so it's hard to tell. Basically, you can create another CTE before prod_prev, something like `WITH products AS ( __your original query__ ), prod_prev AS ( ...`

Comment: Hi Mihe, not sure if the above will work for me, the "RUN_DIFF" is coming in at >1000 for new rows that are only a few mins older than the previous one

Comment: Try this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3e0294/67/0. I've altered it to use the timestamp and to compute (and use) the max diff.